# Getting the ID of a DTS package in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I've got a job set up in SQL Agent, with a number of steps.
These steps all look like:

> DTSRun /~Z0x6B7BDADEAD0D381F601ECC24B
>   C0C4C522870C60DC5EC3D012C5D08A8DEB529CE
>   237A9215B878828FA8AD1FAC5FFB5CAA164ABBE
>   078BD638B2E062391EF98E2C7B31873C81A0291
>   537EBC449B9445233EED18AB93F86CEF58A1C36
>   9CFCA803703A059C2

How can i find out which DTS package that is?

Can a query a db to find out what package id that is? and get the name of the package for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the [DTSRun Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224467%28SQL.80%29.aspx), you can see this:

```
/~Z

Indicates that the command line for dtsrun is encrypted using SQL Server 2000 encryption.
```

Your command line has been encrypted and seems you are out of luck.

However, after further research, I found this:

```
To decrypt what package it is, run from a command window:
DTSRun
/~Z0xA9B18C86BDE97AF20DFA3BDE264EFB9F95433CFF4GG418C085F2649E962AF05F2BB
3010076438B6B4F1E0919E7C362CD05F7CD41C4BBDE76C18CA9A3AE9194EC87B8FF1A115
6A3F286D8EB18A1DCC11D94E02F2759883AA146856CBB649E5F1E97187FC7C517EEDD34F
B6B9AEC98C6857EB12D /!X /!C
```

"This decrypts the encrypt string and stores it in the clipboard. Now,
open textpad/notepad/word/favorite word processing utility and paste the
results. This will give the DTS package name it will run."

Maybe it will work...